# x/crypto: does x/cryto/ssh server supports AcceptEnv?

Tags: go, ssh

as the title describes, does the x/cryto/ssh server supports the AcceptEnv configuration?

If it supports, how to do that or where is the source code?

Comment: `AcceptEnv` isn't part of the ssh protocol, it's just configuration for how the server filters the session environment variables sent by the client. It's up to you to determine how you are going to configure your server implementation.

Answer (score 0):

AcceptEnv itself is not found in [`github.com/golang/crypto`](https://github.com/golang/crypto/search?q=AcceptEnv) (where sources for x/crypto/ssh come from)

When `x/crypto/ssh` is used as an SSH *client* (like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/svett/b7f56afc966a6b6ac2fc) or the project [`melbahja/goph`](https://github.com/melbahja/goph)), AcceptEnv line must be set in the server `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

```golang
// Get new `Goph.Cmd`
cmd, err := client.Command("ls", "-alh", "/tmp")

if err != nil {
    // handle the error!
}

// You can set env vars, but the server must be configured to `AcceptEnv line`.
cmd.Env = []string{"MY_VAR=MYVALUE"}

// Run you command.
err = cmd.Run()
```

But this does not seem directly supported when used as a server.

Comment: `AccpetEnv` isn't part of the protocol,  it's just an openssh configuration option. The server just filters environment variables based on the setting.

Comment: @JimB I thought as much. I wanted to check in the code first, as my answer illustrates.

Comment: I mean, it's "supported" in that it's a concept rather than a feature of the protocol. If you have a server that already accepts client requests, you need to filter those based on your config.